# Run time vector error in loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

My program give me the runtime error for vector iteration , below is my code

```
for (i = 0; i != num_img; ++i)
{
    tmp_img = imread( files[i], 0 ); // load in grayscale.
    resize( tmp_img, tmp_dst, tmp_dst.size() );
    Mat row_img = tmp_dst.reshape( 1, 1 ); // get a one line image.
    row_img.convertTo( training_mat.row(i), CV_32FC1 );
    labels.at< float >(count, 0) = (count<nb_cars)?1:-1; // 1 for car, -1 otherwise*/
}
```

when i check it line by line it show me the error on `tmp_img` in loop 
here is the error
[image]
and sometime its
[image]

Comment: You should check that the size of the vector is at least `num_img`.

Comment: There must be a .size() function to give number of elements. files.size()

Comment: yes i check this , its 42 ,

Comment: Use a debugger ... follow the loop until it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an iterator. They help you to stay in scope;

```
int count = 0;
vector<string>::const_iterator i;
for (i = files.begin(); i != files.end(); ++i){
{
    tmp_img = imread( *i, 0 ); // load in grayscale.
    resize( tmp_img, tmp_dst, tmp_dst.size() );
    Mat row_img = tmp_dst.reshape( 1, 1 ); // get a one line image.
    // copy line and convert to float
    row_img.convertTo( training_mat.row(count), CV_32FC1 );
    labels.at< float >(count, 0) = (count<nb_cars)?1:-1; // 1 for car, -1 otherwise*/
    ++count;
}
```

Comment: No, he should use `const_iterator` if he's going to use iterators at all.

Comment: Right idea, wrong iterator. Change this answer to use a `const_iterator` and you'll likely get back you votes. (and note usage of `*it` for object level access, and `it->memberfn()` for functional access for clarity).

Comment: @WhozCraig Your asking about this answer in above comment ? and i didn't understand `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator`

Comment: using this give me the error on this line
`tmp_img = imread( files.at(i), 0 );`

Comment: @Flying the comment was meant for rukamir's consumption, and a note to you regarding his answer. His approach (using an iterator) is preferred in standard-lib C++. I would suggest you spend an hour reading up on how C++ container iterators work. They're really the best approach for container enumeration (such as your vector of file names). And regarding your error. Change `files.at(i)` to simply `*i` if you're using the code above.

Comment: The correct usages is `tmp_img = imread( *i, 0 );` You are getting an address to the object in the vector so you have to deference it to get down to the actual object.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah i try to focus on it , as i am new to c++ from python

Comment: @rukamir +1,now its work , but what should use for these lines instead of i , as i write early in the above comment new to c++
`row_img.convertTo( training_mat.row(i), CV_32FC1 );
labels.at< float >(i, 0) = (i<nb_cars)?1:-1;`

Comment: `*i` will get you down to where you can access the string data anywhere you are trying to access the actual string. 

I see now that you are also using `i` as a counter. Where this is the case is could declare a `int count = 0;` outside of the for loop and right before the end bracket add a `++count;` and replace everywhere you were using it for the int value to use the `count` variable.

Comment: Can you update the answer , i didn't understand your logic , because i am working on image and `i` contain the rows

Comment: @Flying in any case, the fact that you think you can loop over `num_img` entries in the `files` vector shows that there is something wrong in your code. Looping over the elements of the vector will solve one problem, but you have to understand why `num_img` is inconsistent with the size of `files`.

Comment: @juanchopanza an excellent point (and +1 on your answer, esp for pointing out the larger issue of the unexpected difference).

Comment: @juanchopanza `num_image` contain both positive and negative images , and `files` only contain positive images , let me upload my complete code , i think i have to loop both the positive and negative images , so that it also guess `-1` but how i can do this

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that you are accessing the `files` vector out of range here:

```
for(int i = 0 ;  i < num_img ; i++ )
{
   tmp_img = imread( files[i], 0 ); // i could be larger than files.size()
```

You should make sure that you don't access the vector out of range. Use the [`std::vector::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) method. You can either check that `num_img` is less than or equal to `files.size()`, or remove `num_img` entirely, and loop over the contents of the vector instead.

**Edit** Accessing a vector out of bounds is an error and leads to undefined behaviour. If your program does this, then it is incorrect and must be fixed.

Comment: I know the size of all , files size is 13 and loop size is 42

Comment: @Flying there you go, that is an out of bounds access.

Comment: i change it to `for(int i = 0 ;  i < files.size() ; ++i )` but now its throwing me the error of black screen , which i update in my question

Comment: @Flying I would prefer just using an `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator` to `files.end()`, which outright ensures no index illegal access. Juan is well-versed in this (and eludes to it in the closing sentence of the second paragraph in this answer),  but it appears not to be the case for the OP. C++ iterators keep you out of trouble (usually) and are incredibly flexible. Exploit that.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `operator []` !
You're much better off with `.at()` 
because it checksif `i` is in range and throws `out_of_range` if 
it's not.

```
string YourImagesDirectory="D:\\pics\\";
vector<string> files=listFilesInDirectory(YourImagesDirectory+"*.jpg");
for(size_t i = 0 ;  i < num_img ; i++ )
{
    try
    {
        tmp_img = imread( files.at(i), 0 );
    }
    catch(const std::out_of_range& e)
    {
         std::cerr << "num_img is bigger than files.size()!" << std::endl;
         std::cerr << "Exception caught! (out_of_range): " << e.what() << std::endl;
         break;
    }
    resize( tmp_img, tmp_dst, tmp_dst.size() );
    Mat row_img = tmp_dst.reshape( 1, 1 );
    row_img.convertTo( training_mat.row(i), CV_32FC1 );
    labels.at< float >(i, 0) = (i<nb_cars)?1:-1;
}
```

Comment: it still giving me the black screen error which i update in my question